# spring data cloud , testing a task , running on kubernetes , throwing a maven repo error

Tags: spring-cloud-dataflow

**Where should I set local repo for task launcher and the task app ? 
The spring app json is set with maven local for the deployer  , but  there is some task launcher which is not able to find tthe local that is set in the deployer ~/.m2
Added an app timestamp ... 
Added a timer task called as 'test' using the app** 
Exception ..

```
----------
2020-02-23 22:29:44.484 DEBUG 1 --- [nio-8080-exec-7] o.s.c.d.r.maven.MavenArtifactResolver    : Local repository: /local/m2/repo
2020-02-23 22:29:44.484 DEBUG 1 --- [nio-8080-exec-7] o.s.c.d.r.maven.MavenArtifactResolver    : Remote repositories: repo1,springRepo
2020-02-23 22:29:44.614 DEBUG 1 --- [nio-8080-exec-7] o.s.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager        : Found thread-bound EntityManager [SessionImpl(1372053114<open>)] for JPA transaction
2020-02-23 22:29:44.614 DEBUG 1 --- [nio-8080-exec-7] o.s.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager        : Suspending current transaction, creating new transaction with name [org.springframework.cloud.dataflow.server.service.impl.DefaultTaskExecutionRepositoryService.createTaskExecution]
2020-02-23 22:29:44.615 DEBUG 1 --- [nio-8080-exec-7] o.s.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager        : Opened new EntityManager [SessionImpl(1233051501<open>)] for JPA transaction
2020-02-23 22:29:44.616 DEBUG 1 --- [nio-8080-exec-7] o.s.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager        : Exposing JPA transaction as JDBC [org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect$HibernateConnectionHandle@262b8c26]
2020-02-23 22:29:44.627 DEBUG 1 --- [nio-8080-exec-7] o.s.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager        : Found thread-bound EntityManager [SessionImpl(1233051501<open>)] for JPA transaction
2020-02-23 22:29:44.627 DEBUG 1 --- [nio-8080-exec-7] o.s.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager        : Participating in existing transaction
2020-02-23 22:29:44.665 DEBUG 1 --- [nio-8080-exec-7] o.s.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate               : Executing prepared SQL update
2020-02-23 22:29:44.665 DEBUG 1 --- [nio-8080-exec-7] o.s.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate               : Executing prepared SQL statement [INSERT into TASK_EXECUTION(TASK_EXECUTION_ID, EXIT_CODE, START_TIME, TASK_NAME, LAST_UPDATED, EXTERNAL_EXECUTION_ID, PARENT_EXECUTION_ID)values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)]
2020-02-23 22:29:44.668 DEBUG 1 --- [nio-8080-exec-7] o.s.c.t.r.support.SimpleTaskRepository   : Creating: TaskExecution{executionId=42, parentExecutionId=null, exitCode=null, taskName='test', startTime=null, endTime=null, exitMessage='null', externalExecutionId='null', errorMessage='null', arguments=[]}
2020-02-23 22:29:44.668 DEBUG 1 --- [nio-8080-exec-7] o.s.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager        : Initiating transaction commit
2020-02-23 22:29:44.668 DEBUG 1 --- [nio-8080-exec-7] o.s.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager        : Committing JPA transaction on EntityManager [SessionImpl(1233051501<open>)]
2020-02-23 22:29:44.670 DEBUG 1 --- [nio-8080-exec-7] o.s.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager        : Closing JPA EntityManager [SessionImpl(1233051501<open>)] after transaction
2020-02-23 22:29:44.670 DEBUG 1 --- [nio-8080-exec-7] o.s.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager        : Resuming suspended transaction after completion of inner transaction
2020-02-23 22:29:44.904 DEBUG 1 --- [nio-8080-exec-7] .d.s.s.i.TaskAppDeploymentRequestCreator : Created AppDeploymentRequest = [AppDeploymentRequest@69f8056e commandlineArguments = list['--spring.cloud.data.flow.platformname=default', '--spring.cloud.task.executionid=42'], deploymentProperties = map[[empty]], definition = [AppDefinition@4e92ec3b name = 'test', properties = map['spring.datasource.username' -> 'root', 'spring.cloud.task.name' -> 'test', 'spring.datasource.url' -> 'jdbc:mysql://10.106.204.87:3306/mysql', 'spring.datasource.driverClassName' -> 'org.mariadb.jdbc.Driver', 'spring.datasource.password' -> 'yourpassword']], resource = Docker Resource [docker:springcloudtask/timestamp-task:2.1.0.RELEASE]] AppDefinition = [AppDefinition@4e92ec3b name = 'test', properties = map['spring.datasource.username' -> 'root', 'spring.cloud.task.name' -> 'test', 'spring.datasource.url' -> 'jdbc:mysql://10.106.204.87:3306/mysql', 'spring.datasource.driverClassName' -> 'org.mariadb.jdbc.Driver', 'spring.datasource.password' -> 'yourpassword']]
2020-02-23 22:29:44.958 DEBUG 1 --- [nio-8080-exec-7] o.s.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate               : Executing prepared SQL query
2020-02-23 22:29:44.958 DEBUG 1 --- [nio-8080-exec-7] o.s.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate               : Executing prepared SQL statement [SELECT task_execution_manifest FROM task_execution_metadata m inner join TASK_EXECUTION e on m.task_execution_id = e.TASK_EXECUTION_ID WHERE e.TASK_NAME = ? ORDER BY e.TASK_EXECUTION_ID DESC LIMIT 0, 1]
2020-02-23 22:29:44.971 DEBUG 1 --- [nio-8080-exec-7] o.s.c.d.r.maven.MavenArtifactResolver    : Local repository: ?/.m2/repository
2020-02-23 22:29:44.971 DEBUG 1 --- [nio-8080-exec-7] o.s.c.d.r.maven.MavenArtifactResolver    : Remote repositories:
2020-02-23 22:29:44.972 DEBUG 1 --- [nio-8080-exec-7] o.s.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager        : Initiating transaction rollback
2020-02-23 22:29:44.973 DEBUG 1 --- [nio-8080-exec-7] o.s.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager        : Rolling back JPA transaction on EntityManager [SessionImpl(1372053114<open>)]
2020-02-23 22:29:44.975 DEBUG 1 --- [nio-8080-exec-7] o.s.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager        : Not closing pre-bound JPA EntityManager after transaction
2020-02-23 22:29:44.980 ERROR 1 --- [nio-8080-exec-7] o.s.c.d.s.c.RestControllerAdvice         : Caught exception while handling a request

java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to generate query
    at org.springframework.cloud.dataflow.server.repository.JdbcDataflowTaskExecutionMetadataDao.getLatestManifest(JdbcDataflowTaskExecutionMetadataDao.java:153)
    at org.springframework.cloud.dataflow.server.service.impl.DefaultTaskExecutionService.executeTask(DefaultTaskExecutionService.java:248)
    at org.springframework.cloud.dataflow.server.service.impl.DefaultTaskExecutionService$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$422cda43.invoke(<generated>)
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:218)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(CglibAopProxy.java:769)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:163)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.proceed(CglibAopProxy.java:747)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:366)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:99)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
    at org.s
....................
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unable to deserialize manifest
    at org.springframework.cloud.dataflow.server.repository.JdbcDataflowTaskExecutionMetadataDao.lambda$getLatestManifest$0(JdbcDataflowTaskExecutionMetadataDao.java:145)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.RowMapperResultSetExtractor.extractData(RowMapperResultSetExtractor.java:94)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.RowMapperResultSetExtractor.extractData(RowMapperResultSetExtractor.java:61)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate$1.doInPreparedStatement(JdbcTemplate.java:679)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.execute(JdbcTemplate.java:617)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.query(JdbcTemplate.java:669)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.query(JdbcTemplate.java:694)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.query(JdbcTemplate.java:748)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.namedparam.NamedParameterJdbcTemplate.queryForObject(NamedParameterJdbcTemplate.java:236)
    at org.springframework.cloud.dataflow.server.repository.JdbcDataflowTaskExecutionMetadataDao.getLatestManifest(JdbcDataflowTaskExecutionMetadataDao.java:139)
    ... 71 common frames omitted
**Caused by: com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: Unable to create directory for local repository: ?/.m2/repository (through reference chain:
** org.springframework.cloud.dataflow.core.TaskManifest["taskDeploymentRequest"]->org.springframework.cloud.deployer.spi.core.AppDeploymentRequest["resource"])
```

Answer (score 0):

It dissappeared after adding these

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: scdf-server
  labels:
    app: scdf-server
data:
  application.yaml: |-
    security:
      basic:
        enabled: true
        realm: Spring Cloud Data Flow
    spring:
      cloud:
        deployer:
          kubernetes:
            accounts:
              default:
                podSecurityContext:
                  runAsUser: 1000
                  fsGroup: 100
                envVarsToInherit: "SPRING_APPLICATION_JSON"
                imagePullSecret: dockercred
                environmentVariables: ''
        scheduler:
          kubernetes:
            accounts:
              default:
                podSecurityContext:
                  runAsUser: 1000
                  fsGroup: 100
                envVarsToInherit: "SPRING_APPLICATION_JSON"
                imagePullSecret: dockercred
                environmentVariables: ''
        dataflow:
          server:
            cloudfoundry:
              debugReactor: true
          security:
            authentication:
              file:
                enabled: true
                users:
                  admin: "{noop}admin, ROLE_MANAGE, ROLE_VIEW"
                  user: "{noop}password, ROLE_VIEW, ROLE_CREATE"
          task:
            platform:
              kubernetes:
                environmentVariables: 'JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS=-Dlogging.level.org.springframework=DEBUG'
                accounts:
                  default:
                    podSecurityContext:
                      runAsUser: 1000
                      fsGroup: 100
                    inheritLogging: true
                    envVarsToInherit: "SPRING_APPLICATION_JSON"
                    imagePullSecret: dockercred
                    environmentVariables: ''
      datasource:
        url: jdbc:mysql://${MYSQL_SERVICE_HOST}:${MYSQL_SERVICE_PORT}/mysql
        validationQuery: "SELECT 1"
```